# PHP JSON Twitter Trends

Tags: php, json, twitter

Can anyone spot the problem with this PHP, nothing appears on the screen:

```
<?php
function get_data($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

$url='http://search.twitter.com/trends.json';
$obj = json_decode(get_data($url));
foreach ($obj as $item) {
$trend = $item->name;
$link = $item->url;
echo "<a href='.$link.'>".$trend."</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What says var_dump($obj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looping over the collection properly. Use:

```
foreach ($obj->trends as $item) {
```

Your `$obj` is an object (just a `stdClass`) with a `trends` property which is an array of objects with `name` and `url` properties.  This reflects the structure of the JSON which looks like:

```
{
    "trends": [
        {
            "name": "#yepthatsme",
            "url": "http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23yepthatsme"
        },
        {
            "name": "Miley Citrus",
            "url": "http://search.twitter.com/search?q=Miley+Citrus"
        },
        /* lots more */
        {
            "name": "Keith Olbermann",
            "url": "http://search.twitter.com/search?q=Keith+Olbermann"
        }
    ],
    "as_of": "Sat, 22 Jan 2011 13:37:25 +0000"
}
```